# QuerySelector not working after fetching template - WebComponents

Tags: templates, web-component

The TeleMenu is having two buttons and I'm trying to grab them, but there is a problem with this.shadowRoot.querySelector.

Error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null

Code:

```
class TeleMenu extends HTMLElement {

buttons = [];

constructor() {
    super();

    fetch('tele-menu.html')
        .then(resp => resp.text())
        .then(resp => {
            this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
                .innerHTML = resp
        })

    this.buttons = Array.from(this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('button'));
}
```

Can you help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetch is asynchronous, you are executing `.querySelectorAll` long **before** the innerHTML is set

```js
constructor() {
    super();

    fetch('tele-menu.html')
        .then(resp => resp.text())
        .then(resp => {
            this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
                .innerHTML = resp
        })

    this.buttons = Array.from(this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('button'));
}
```

The Google and MDN documentation is wrong with ***run super() first***

`super()` sets and **creates** the 'this' scope.

So you can't call `this` before super has run.. that's the only limitation

You can do:

```js
constructor() {
    fetch('tele-menu.html')
        .then(resp => resp.text())
        .then(resp => {
            super().attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
                   .innerHTML = resp;
            this.buttons = [...this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('button')];//modern way
            // do more here
        })
}
```

https://javascript.info/async-await probably helps in keeping your code cleaner

Comment: Very much thanks for your help. Now I understand the problem. Do you mean with "https://javascript.info/async-await probably helps in keeping your code cleaner" to use async instead of promise with .then?

Comment: Yes, less code, easier to read, but programming is art and the artist decides what to do and use.

Comment: if you are satisfied you can mark it answered, tnx